# How to set win occurrence or percentage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, probability, percentage

I have a number game (lotto) where there's an array of 1 - 36.

```
  myNum = [1,2,3...36];
```

The player is to choose 6 numbers from 1 - 36 (into an array).
I generate random 6 numbers too (into another array).
And the player wins a certain amount depending on the number of matches (with mine).

My intention and my issue now is to determine the number of times the player wins,
If there is a match with mine, it should be added to the wins and if there's none it should not.
This is how I would love to set the win percentage:

```
   winPercentage = 80; //80 percent
```

or any other means.

I did some tries with my little JS knowledge, searched the internet and SO but but could't understand/find a way. Someone please help

Comment: what should happen with 80 percent?

Comment: You can't set the percentage for a system like that, only calculate it.

Comment: @NinaScholz, it means, say for example the player plays the game 100 times, he should win only 80 times. Which means, the number of times the player will have at least a match with my number will be 80, not more

Comment: @Jonathan how do I do that, please?

Comment: Do you try to find the win percentage? or want to limit the win percentage should max 80 percent? which one is your question.

Comment: @AtiqulAlam I want to limit the win percentage to 80 percent, exactly.

Comment: @OlawaleOladiran, as jonathan wrote, lotto does not work with a certain percantage to win. the onl possible value, you could change is the amount, you like to return on various combinations, like 3 to 6 matching values.

Comment: @OlawaleOladiran, As you mention in the comment you need to limit the user win chance to 80% you need to manipulate your random generated array. Say for example if you set user to choose 6 random number from 1-36 so s/he have maximum 4 matches with your one, cause 80% of 6 is 4.8, so we take the floor value which is 4. This is what may be a behind the scene.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I'm gonna try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly that you want to calculate the win percentage of the player against you.

If I am right then you need to calculate **the total match played** and **the number of matches the player win**.

Say,

```
the_total_match_played (TM) = 80;
player_win(PW) = 30;

win_percengage(WP) = (PW * 100) / TM;
WP = (30 * 100) / 80;
   = 37.5%
```

**Note:** If I am wrong understanding your problem please feel free to comment.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. What I want is that, say the player plays this game 100 times, he should win exactly 80 times and lose the remaining 20 games. Meanwhile, I can randomly make the player win now and then lose later but at the end, the player's overall win should be 80 out of 100 tries.

Comment: What would be the win condition?

Comment: the win condition is whenever one of the player's number matches one of my generated numbers.

Comment: I think it's hard to define the win percentage exactly 80%. Say if the player plays 6 matches then he has to win 4.8 matches (not 4 nor 5). It's not possible to win 4.8 (fractional) matches.

Comment: Yea, it could be more, like 90%, I just used that to explain. And with the replies I've gotten, it seems I'll have to manipulate my randomly generated numbers

Answer (score 0):

Basically the expression to evaluate is that

**first OR second OR third OR fourth OR fifth OR sixth**

**P(first) = P(second) = P(third) = P(fourth) = P(fifth) = P(sixth) = 1/36**

One would intuitively think that the result would be

**1/36 + 1/36 + 1/36 + 1/36 + 1/36 + 1/36 = 6 * 1/36 = 1/6**,

but we need to keep track of the cases which were duplicates. For example, if the first was chosen and the second as well, that would be calculated twice with the above formula, which would be incorrect. So the formula is

> 1/36 +
>
> 35/36 * 1/36 +
>
> (1 - 35/36 * 1/36) * 1/36 +
>
> (1 - (1 - 35/36 * 1/36) * 1/36) * 1/36 +
>
> (1 - (1 - (1 - 35/36 * 1/36) * 1/36) * 1/36) * 1/36 +
>
> (1 - (1 - (1 - (1 - 35/36 * 1/36) * 1/36) * 1/36) * 1/36) * 1/36

which is

**0.16289262235174626 ~ 16.28%**

sorry, it's *not* 80%. You can assign this value **0.16289262235174626** to a variable like

```
var winChance = 0.16289262235174626;
```

and whenever you want a percent, compute

```
100 * winChance
```